Comparing the acidic strengths of four substituted phenols (4-X-Ph-OH)

Compare the acidic strengths of 4-nitrophenol, 4-hydroxybenzaldehyde, 4-hydroxybenzenesulfonic acid, and 4-hydroxybenzoic acid:


In this problem, I was asked to determine the order of acidic strength, also referred to as acidity of given phenol compounds. As usual, I removed the hydrogen atom from the $\ce{OH}$ group of the phenol portion of the molecule. However, when solving the problem, the professor removed the hydrogen from the $\ce{SO3H}$ and $\ce{COOH}$ groups in the last two molecules.
When I searched online, I discovered that when determining the acidity of molecules that have more than one acidic hydrogen, the most acidic hydrogen is removed to form the most stable conjugate base, following natural tendencies. This explanation seemed reasonable to me.
The challenge arises when comparing the stability of the four conjugate bases formed. Determining the stability of the conjugate bases of the first and second molecules is straightforward because the hydrogen is removed from the same part of each molecule, allowing the effect of substituents to determine the stability of the resulting conjugate base. However, in this case, the hydrogen is removed from different parts of each molecule, making the approach less direct and more complex. For example, in the first two molecules, the hydrogen is removed from the $\ce{OH}$ group. In the third molecule, it is removed from the $\ce{SO3H}$ group, and in the fourth molecule, it is removed from the $\ce{COOH}$ group.
So, what approach should be used to solve these types of problems? My current thought is that we need to assess the extent of resonance. However, in the back of my mind, I am also considering the type of mesomeric effect involved, whether it is -M or +M. Are other related factors involved? Does the extent of resonance dominate all of these considerations? Is it the primary rule for determining the stability of conjugate bases?

See here for some insights.

First, you could compare the acidity of the functional groups of alcohols, carboxylic acids and sulfonic acids. This is the primary difference. Then, if necessary, look at the subtle difference of changes many bonds away.

@Karsten, thanks for pointing out the correct approach, but I didn’t understand what this means: "Then, if necessary, look at the subtle difference of changes many bonds away."

@MadaraUchiha Yes, the order of acidity is fundamental in basic organic chemistry. Here is the correct sequence:
Sulfonic acids (R-SO₃H) > Carboxylic acids (R-COOH) > Phenols (Ar-OH) > Alcohols (R-OH)

@MadaraUchiha If you're confused about the mesomeric effect due to the OH group in compounds 3 and 4, then please redraw the structure. You'll find that the mesomeric effect of the OH group actually makes the resonance more extensive!

What I meant to say: structures 1 and 2 have an -OH group as the most acidic group. To compare the two, you have to look at the other functional group in the ring. Structure 3 and 4 are different in the functional group that has the most acidic group, so what else is on the ring is secondary.

@Karsten Thank you! It really helped.
